# Mysql only using 10% of cache

Tags: mysql, innodb, high-availability, cache

I have a dedicated Mysql server that only uses 1.1 GB out of 16 GB ram (picture link 1). I belive this leads to my Disk I/O utilization beeing at 75% peaks (picture link1). How can i configure sql right so i don't get any I/O utilization peaks? Does this have to do with my caching config? and how can i turn my database to use more chache? 
Both mysql config and mysql status are pasted bellow:

graph of memfree and I/O spike at 3AM(without much traffic to server) : [http://imgur.com/a/Jnux2](https://imgur.com/a/Jnux2)

mysql config:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = xxx
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = xxx
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = xxxx
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 64M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
table_cache            = 128
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size = 32M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 32M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 64M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

mysql status:

```
+------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value       |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Aborted_clients                          | 0           |
| Aborted_connects                         | 0           |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                    | 0           |
| Binlog_cache_use                         | 0           |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use               | 0           |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                    | 0           |
| Bytes_received                           | 137         |
| Bytes_sent                               | 185         |
| Com_admin_commands                       | 0           |
| Com_assign_to_keycache                   | 0           |
| Com_alter_db                             | 0           |
| Com_alter_db_upgrade                     | 0           |
| Com_alter_event                          | 0           |
| Com_alter_function                       | 0           |
| Com_alter_procedure                      | 0           |
| Com_alter_server                         | 0           |
| Com_alter_table                          | 0           |
| Com_alter_tablespace                     | 0           |
| Com_analyze                              | 0           |
| Com_begin                                | 0           |
| Com_binlog                               | 0           |
| Com_call_procedure                       | 0           |
| Com_change_db                            | 0           |
| Com_change_master                        | 0           |
| Com_check                                | 0           |
| Com_checksum                             | 0           |
| Com_commit                               | 0           |
| Com_create_db                            | 0           |
| Com_create_event                         | 0           |
| Com_create_function                      | 0           |
| Com_create_index                         | 0           |
| Com_create_procedure                     | 0           |
| Com_create_server                        | 0           |
| Com_create_table                         | 0           |
| Com_create_trigger                       | 0           |
| Com_create_udf                           | 0           |
| Com_create_user                          | 0           |
| Com_create_view                          | 0           |
| Com_dealloc_sql                          | 0           |
| Com_delete                               | 0           |
| Com_delete_multi                         | 0           |
| Com_do                                   | 0           |
| Com_drop_db                              | 0           |
| Com_drop_event                           | 0           |
| Com_drop_function                        | 0           |
| Com_drop_index                           | 0           |
| Com_drop_procedure                       | 0           |
| Com_drop_server                          | 0           |
| Com_drop_table                           | 0           |
| Com_drop_trigger                         | 0           |
| Com_drop_user                            | 0           |
| Com_drop_view                            | 0           |
| Com_empty_query                          | 0           |
| Com_execute_sql                          | 0           |
| Com_flush                                | 0           |
| Com_grant                                | 0           |
| Com_ha_close                             | 0           |
| Com_ha_open                              | 0           |
| Com_ha_read                              | 0           |
| Com_help                                 | 0           |
| Com_insert                               | 0           |
| Com_insert_select                        | 0           |
| Com_install_plugin                       | 0           |
| Com_kill                                 | 0           |
| Com_load                                 | 0           |
| Com_lock_tables                          | 0           |
| Com_optimize                             | 0           |
| Com_preload_keys                         | 0           |
| Com_prepare_sql                          | 0           |
| Com_purge                                | 0           |
| Com_purge_before_date                    | 0           |
| Com_release_savepoint                    | 0           |
| Com_rename_table                         | 0           |
| Com_rename_user                          | 0           |
| Com_repair                               | 0           |
| Com_replace                              | 0           |
| Com_replace_select                       | 0           |
| Com_reset                                | 0           |
| Com_resignal                             | 0           |
| Com_revoke                               | 0           |
| Com_revoke_all                           | 0           |
| Com_rollback                             | 0           |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint                | 0           |
| Com_savepoint                            | 0           |
| Com_select                               | 1           |
| Com_set_option                           | 0           |
| Com_signal                               | 0           |
| Com_show_authors                         | 0           |
| Com_show_binlog_events                   | 0           |
| Com_show_binlogs                         | 0           |
| Com_show_charsets                        | 0           |
| Com_show_collations                      | 0           |
| Com_show_contributors                    | 0           |
| Com_show_create_db                       | 0           |
| Com_show_create_event                    | 0           |
| Com_show_create_func                     | 0           |
| Com_show_create_proc                     | 0           |
| Com_show_create_table                    | 0           |
| Com_show_create_trigger                  | 0           |
| Com_show_databases                       | 0           |
| Com_show_engine_logs                     | 0           |
| Com_show_engine_mutex                    | 0           |
| Com_show_engine_status                   | 0           |
| Com_show_events                          | 0           |
| Com_show_errors                          | 0           |
| Com_show_fields                          | 0           |
| Com_show_function_status                 | 0           |
| Com_show_grants                          | 0           |
| Com_show_keys                            | 0           |
| Com_show_master_status                   | 0           |
| Com_show_open_tables                     | 0           |
| Com_show_plugins                         | 0           |
| Com_show_privileges                      | 0           |
| Com_show_procedure_status                | 0           |
| Com_show_processlist                     | 0           |
| Com_show_profile                         | 0           |
| Com_show_profiles                        | 0           |
| Com_show_relaylog_events                 | 0           |
| Com_show_slave_hosts                     | 0           |
| Com_show_slave_status                    | 0           |
| Com_show_status                          | 1           |
| Com_show_storage_engines                 | 0           |
| Com_show_table_status                    | 0           |
| Com_show_tables                          | 0           |
| Com_show_triggers                        | 0           |
| Com_show_variables                       | 0           |
| Com_show_warnings                        | 0           |
| Com_slave_start                          | 0           |
| Com_slave_stop                           | 0           |
| Com_stmt_close                           | 0           |
| Com_stmt_execute                         | 0           |
| Com_stmt_fetch                           | 0           |
| Com_stmt_prepare                         | 0           |
| Com_stmt_reprepare                       | 0           |
| Com_stmt_reset                           | 0           |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data                  | 0           |
| Com_truncate                             | 0           |
| Com_uninstall_plugin                     | 0           |
| Com_unlock_tables                        | 0           |
| Com_update                               | 0           |
| Com_update_multi                         | 0           |
| Com_xa_commit                            | 0           |
| Com_xa_end                               | 0           |
| Com_xa_prepare                           | 0           |
| Com_xa_recover                           | 0           |
| Com_xa_rollback                          | 0           |
| Com_xa_start                             | 0           |
| Compression                              | OFF         |
| Connections                              | 112016      |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                  | 0           |
| Created_tmp_files                        | 6           |
| Created_tmp_tables                       | 0           |
| Delayed_errors                           | 0           |
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0           |
| Delayed_writes                           | 0           |
| Flush_commands                           | 1           |
| Handler_commit                           | 0           |
| Handler_delete                           | 0           |
| Handler_discover                         | 0           |
| Handler_prepare                          | 0           |
| Handler_read_first                       | 0           |
| Handler_read_key                         | 0           |
| Handler_read_last                        | 0           |
| Handler_read_next                        | 0           |
| Handler_read_prev                        | 0           |
| Handler_read_rnd                         | 0           |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                    | 0           |
| Handler_rollback                         | 0           |
| Handler_savepoint                        | 0           |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback               | 0           |
| Handler_update                           | 0           |
| Handler_write                            | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data            | 4519        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data            | 74039296    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty           | 10          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty           | 163840      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed         | 240843      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free            | 650608      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc            | 232         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total           | 655359      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd        | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead            | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted    | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests         | 210271975   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                 | 3619        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free             | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests        | 915366      |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                       | 99545       |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs               | 0           |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                | 0           |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes               | 0           |
| Innodb_data_read                         | 66637824    |
| Innodb_data_reads                        | 3944        |
| Innodb_data_writes                       | 333813      |
| Innodb_data_written                      | 7983191552  |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written               | 240843      |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                      | 7871        |
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins              | ON          |
| Innodb_log_waits                         | 0           |
| Innodb_log_write_requests                | 111349      |
| Innodb_log_writes                        | 80086       |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                     | 83847       |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs             | 0           |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes             | 0           |
| Innodb_os_log_written                    | 89334784    |
| Innodb_page_size                         | 16384       |
| Innodb_pages_created                     | 586         |
| Innodb_pages_read                        | 3933        |
| Innodb_pages_written                     | 240843      |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits            | 0           |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                     | 317902      |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                 | 1218        |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                 | 10899       |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                    | 261         |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                      | 291         |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                     | 15683       |
| Innodb_rows_read                         | 91194381    |
| Innodb_rows_updated                      | 104330      |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes           | 0           |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                   | 0           |
| Key_blocks_unused                        | 53578       |
| Key_blocks_used                          | 7           |
| Key_read_requests                        | 30          |
| Key_reads                                | 7           |
| Key_write_requests                       | 0           |
| Key_writes                               | 0           |
| Last_query_cost                          | 0.000000    |
| Max_used_connections                     | 12          |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                 | 0           |
| Open_files                               | 68          |
| Open_streams                             | 0           |
| Open_table_definitions                   | 90          |
| Open_tables                              | 128         |
| Opened_files                             | 691         |
| Opened_table_definitions                 | 0           |
| Opened_tables                            | 0           |
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost     | 0           |
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost   | 0           |
| Performance_schema_file_classes_lost     | 0           |
| Performance_schema_file_handles_lost     | 0           |
| Performance_schema_file_instances_lost   | 0           |
| Performance_schema_locker_lost           | 0           |
| Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost    | 0           |
| Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost  | 0           |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost   | 0           |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost | 0           |
| Performance_schema_table_handles_lost    | 0           |
| Performance_schema_table_instances_lost  | 0           |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0           |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0           |
| Prepared_stmt_count                      | 0           |
| Qcache_free_blocks                       | 572         |
| Qcache_free_memory                       | 27882952    |
| Qcache_hits                              | 266251      |
| Qcache_inserts                           | 333860      |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes                     | 0           |
| Qcache_not_cached                        | 11873       |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache                  | 1148        |
| Qcache_total_blocks                      | 3059        |
| Queries                                  | 1139446     |
| Questions                                | 2           |
| Rpl_status                               | AUTH_MASTER |
| Select_full_join                         | 0           |
| Select_full_range_join                   | 0           |
| Select_range                             | 0           |
| Select_range_check                       | 0           |
| Select_scan                              | 0           |
| Slave_heartbeat_period                   | 0.000       |
| Slave_open_temp_tables                   | 0           |
| Slave_received_heartbeats                | 0           |
| Slave_retried_transactions               | 0           |
| Slave_running                            | OFF         |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0           |
| Slow_queries                             | 0           |
| Sort_merge_passes                        | 0           |
| Sort_range                               | 0           |
| Sort_rows                                | 0           |
| Sort_scan                                | 0           |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates                  | 0           |
| Ssl_accepts                              | 0           |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits                  | 0           |
| Ssl_cipher                               |             |
| Ssl_cipher_list                          |             |
| Ssl_client_connects                      | 0           |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                 | 0           |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth                     | 0           |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode                      | 0           |
| Ssl_default_timeout                      | 0           |
| Ssl_finished_accepts                     | 0           |
| Ssl_finished_connects                    | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits                   | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses                 | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode                   | NONE        |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows              | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_size                   | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts               | 0           |
| Ssl_sessions_reused                      | 0           |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries           | 0           |
| Ssl_verify_depth                         | 0           |
| Ssl_verify_mode                          | 0           |
| Ssl_version                              |             |
| Table_locks_immediate                    | 508814      |
| Table_locks_waited                       | 0           |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used                    | 0           |
| Tc_log_page_size                         | 0           |
| Tc_log_page_waits                        | 0           |
| Threads_cached                           | 7           |
| Threads_connected                        | 1           |
| Threads_created                          | 150         |
| Threads_running                          | 1           |
| Uptime                                   | 42107       |
| Uptime_since_flush_status                | 42107       |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31754/discussion-between-lars-erik-and-karoly-nagy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had 2 problems:

1) We had one mysql query that used three joins. Turns out this function was crashing Mysql. We rewrote this query to use 4 mysql queries without joins and that solved that problem. (Bit of a hot-fix, we will probably rewrite the function so it is possible to cache it). See [Disk I/O Utilization at 95%](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121248/disk-i-o-utilization-at-95)

2) We were experiencing around 99.9 % I/O wait when we only used 10% cache. We tried to edit the mysql config (quoted at the bottom). This helped a lot but did not fix the problem. It turned out another user on the shared server was causing 99.8% I/O spikes. After contacting our server provider they moving the server to another partition and the problem was fixed.

```
table_open_cache = 1024 
sort_buffer_size = 4M 
read_buffer_size = 128k 
query_cache_size= 128M 
query_cache_type = 1 
tmp_table_size = 64M 
thread_cache_size = 20 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M 
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M 
innodb_log_file_size = 64M 
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M 
innodb_file_per_table innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```